# Is it possible to adjust your walk speed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I'm sneaking around, I can move more slowly and quietly by holding <kbd>shift</kbd>.

But walking this way is *really* slow. I would like to move a little bit faster, but not full speed.

On a console I imagine you have much finer control over how fast you move with the joysticks. Is there any way to accomplish this on the PC (without an external joystick)?

Perhaps there is a console command or config file setting that will change the % speed modifier that holding down <kbd>shift</kbd> uses?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change your *base* speed using the console, which you can open using the <kbd>~</kbd> key (or whatever key is to the left of the number strip at the top of your keyboard).

Type `player.setav speedmult x` where `x` is the number you want for your walking speed; the default is 100.

You can either increase or decrease this number.  Increasing it higher will result in super fast running which man ruin the reality of the game.

I'd recommend `player.setav speedmult 125`.

In my opinion the default running is way too fast, and the default walking is too slow.  While holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to sprint is perfect.  The only other way I know to edit these values is to open the core files, like XML with a text editor, but I won't go into that much detail here.  You should be able to Google it.

Comment: I think you need to sprint for a moment after setting `speedmult` for changes to take effect. Or I guess switching into sneak mode for a few seconds makes the changes take effect too.

Comment: Note that this changes both the walking speed and the running speed.

Answer (score 10):

Morebatteries' answer works pretty well - but I've also discovered a mod that is a little more nuanced.

[**Realistic Running Speed**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1931)

According to the documentation:

> It adjusts the speeds of the player, NPCs and horses by the following amounts:
>
> Character Sneak Walk  +15%
> Character Sneak Run   -25%
> Character Walk        +15%
> Character Run         -20%
> Character Sprint      -20%
> Horse Walk            +5%
> Horse Run             0%
> Horse Sprint          +5%

After a quick play, it appears to be decent.

Answer (score 3):

There is unfortunately not a lot of control on PC; you have only full blown sneak running or tip-toed *Hall of the Mountain King* sneaking.  Getting a wired Xbox controller is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

My [Realistic Humanoid Movement Speed](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/32229) plugin fixes everything. Your walk/run/sprint/sneak/horse move speed will be realistic.

Comment: When you answer with a recommendation for something you made, you really do need to disclose that conflict of interest. It's not a problem to recommend your own work, only failing to disclose is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to permanently run. The default for sprint is <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>caps lock</kbd> and it adjusts the speed between intolerably slow and "still slow as molasses but slightly better".