# Why isn't "player.setav speedmult" working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Its been ages since I played on PS3, and I just started playing again on PC. The world is big, which is fine except I spend way way more real time than I'd like doing nothing but walking/running around. Especially when I'm overburdened and trying to walk around selling stuff, but running around from place to place is tedious as well.

I googled it, and I found a couple mods which increase walk speed, but decrease run speed for whatever reason, and that's not what I want. I found this Q&A: "[Is it possible to adjust your walk speed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36069/is-it-possible-to-adjust-your-walk-speed)".

The answer there doesn't seem to work for me. I tried "player.setav speedmult 125" and "player.setav speedmult 200" and others, but it makes no difference. **Why isn't that working?**

Do I have to type a command, or manually edit a file to do this, or something? Is it disabled in the Steam version?

Comment: Have you considered a horse?

Comment: It’s not too hard to edit a mod to get whatever movement speed you want, if you’re OK with using TES5Edit. It seems like that speedmult command should have worked though. Did the console command give you any errors?

Comment: try setting the speedmult higher, try something like 400. it should work if you type it correctly into the console. you are using the console to do the command correct?

Comment: That other question is more "how do you do this", and this one is more "setav speedmult isn't working, why?". Different enough for me. Might've been better as a comment on the answer, but like they said, can't comment.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer A horse can't help me in town.

Comment: @Armadillo I've never heard of it, was playing on PS3 last time so I didn't have mods. I'll check it out I suppose.

Comment: @Dragonrage I just tried 400, 1000, 10000, and tried using forceav instead of setav, still no effect. I read something somewhere after posting this that said switching in and out of stealth mode may be required to activate it but that didn't work either.

Comment: @DCShannon I did, but it seems someone has edited that out and made other slight changes to my original question. That is very disconcerting... On top of that the edit is credited to you...

Comment: I just tried modav and combined with going in and out of stealth to activate it it did work, I think it was at 10,000, basically teleported forward until I hit a wall. I don't seem to be able to lower the speed with modav, but I just realized I can use forceav to set it to lower and higher speeds I just have to activate it by going in and out of stealth mode and wait several seconds (before or after going in and out of stealth mode). So I guess this question is resolved, thank you everyone for replying, and for your patience.

Comment: @PålHart You did what? You can always roll an edit back if you like. I was mostly trying to make it look less like a duplicate to stave off being closed.

Comment: Oh, wait: after using speedmult, sprint. The setting should take effect after that. (I think that works.) But I guess you figured out another way to do it.